# What is the difference between json.dumps and json.load?

Tags: python, json

What is the difference between `json.dumps` and `json.load`?

From my understanding, one loads JSON into a dictionary and another loads into objects.

Answer (score 225, accepted):

[`dumps`](https://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.dumps) takes an object and produces a string:

```
>>> a = {'foo': 3}
>>> json.dumps(a)
'{"foo": 3}'
```

[`load`](https://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.load) would take a file-like object, read the data from that object, and use that string to create an object:

```
with open('file.json') as fh:
    a = json.load(fh)
```

Note that [`dump`](https://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.dump) and `load` convert between files and objects, while `dumps` and [`loads`](https://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.loads) convert between *strings* and objects. You can think of the `s`-less functions as wrappers around the `s` functions:

```
def dump(obj, fh):
    fh.write(dumps(obj))

def load(fh):
    return loads(fh.read())
```

Comment: This is very helpful for my understanding. Still I'm a little confused as I thought everything is an object in Python. Wouldn't string be an object in itself? How could you convert between the two then? Sorry for the silly question.

Comment: I'm using `object` in the sense of "something of a type other than `str`". A string like `'"foo"'` is decoded to the *Python* `str` object `'foo'`; a string like `"[1,2,3]"` is decoded to the Python list `[1,2,3]`, etc.

Comment: `dumps()`- encoding to JSON objects 
`dump()`- encoded string writing on file
`loads()`- Decode the JSON string
`load()`- Decode while JSON file read

Answer (score 100):

json loads -> returns an object from a string representing a json object.

json dumps -> returns a string representing a json object from an object.

load and dump -> read/write from/to file instead of string

Comment: >  json dumps -> returns a string representing a json object from a dict.

That's close, but it doesn't have to be a dict you pass in to json.dumps(). You can pass a list, or a string, or a boolean..