# Php json array into Python3

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have a php script that outputs a json array that looks like this...

```
[{"year":"2016","Month":"Apr","the_days":"16, 29, 30"},
{"year":"2016","Month":"May","the_days":"13, 27"},
{"year":"2016","Month":"Jun","the_days":"10, 11, 24"},
{"year":"2016","Month":"Jul","the_days":"08, 22, 23"},
{"year":"2016","Month":"Aug","the_days":"06, 20"},
{"year":"2016","Month":"Sep","the_days":"02, 03, 16, 17, 30"},
{"year":"2016","Month":"Oct","the_days":"01, 14, 15, 29"},
{"year":"2016","Month":"Nov","the_days":"25"},
{"year":"2016","Month":"Dec","the_days":"09, 10, 23, 24"}]
```

I'm trying to put together some Python that will (eventually) output something like....

```
Apr: 16, 29, 30
May: 13, 27
//etc
```

...but I'm not having any luck pulling the array out.
This is code that I'm using in Python3 (that I've pulled together from other Stack questions that I've searched for).

```
import urllib.request
import json

response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.captainobviousobviously.co.uk/private/Apijson.php')
content = response.read()   
data = json.load(content.decode('utf-8'))

print(data)
```

This is the error that I'm getting...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Python/availableDates.py", line 6, in <module>
data = json.load(content.decode('utf-8'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 265, in load
return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

I'm not really sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace 
    `data = json.load(content.decode('utf-8'))`
with
    `data = json.loads(content.decode('utf-8'))`

'load' is for files and 'loads' for strings.

Refer [What is the difference between json.dumps and json.load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911336/what-is-the-difference-between-json-dumps-and-json-load).

As for the code for your problem

```
for i in data:
    print (str(i['Month'])+":"+str(i['the_days']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `json.loads` instead. `load` is for loading from a stream, such as a file, whereas `loads` loads from a string.

```
data = json.loads(content.decode('utf-8'))
```

From the Python documentation:

> **`json.load`**
>
> Deserialize fp (a `.read()`-supporting file-like object containing a JSON document) to a Python object using this conversion table.

A string isn't a *"file-like object"*, which is why you get your error - the JSON is trying to call `.read` on the string, but that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `json.loads(<json str>)`. If you want you can do the following

```
content = response.read().decode()
data = json.loads(content)
for d in data:
    print(d["Month"], d["the_days"], sep=":")
```