# Python Request Session JIRA REST post http 405

Tags: python-requests, jira-rest-api

Using python requests session I can connect to JIRA and retrieve issue information ...

```
session = requests.Session()
headers = {"Authorization": "Basic %s" % bas64_val}
session.post(jira_rest_url, headers=headers)
jira = session.get(jira_srch_issue_url + select_fields)

# select_fields = the fields I want from the issue
```

Now I'm trying to post a payload via the JIRA API, using a fixed issue url e.g. "https://my_jira_server.com:1234/rest/api/latest/issue/KEY-9876"

Which should be a case of the following, given: https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/about-the-jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-edit-issues

```
payload = { "update": {
    "fixVersions": [ {"set": "release-2.139.0"} ]
}}
posted = session.post(jira_task_url, data=payload)

# returns <Response [405]>
# jira_task_url = https://my_jira_server.com:1234/rest/api/latest/issue/KEY-9876
```

But this doesn't appear to work! Looking into the **http 405** response, suggests that my payload is not properly formatted! Which notably, is the not easiest thing to diagnose.

What am I doing wrong here? Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Please note, I am **not** looking to use the python jira module, I am using requests.session to manage several sessions for different systems i.e. JIRA, TeamCity, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution! I had **two** problems:

**1**) The actual syntax structure should have been:

```
fix_version = { "update": { "fixVersions": [ {"set" : [{ "name" : "release-2.139.0" }]}]
```

**2**) To ensure the payload is actually presented as JSON, use json.dumps() which takes an object and produces a string (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911336/what-is-the-difference-between-json-dumps-and-json-load)) AND set 'content-type' to 'application/json':

```
payload = json.dumps(fix_version)
app_json = { 'content-type': 'application/json' }
session.put(https://.../rest/api/latest/issue/KEY-9876, headers=app_json, data=payload)
```

Rather than trying to define the JSON manually!

Comment: In the case of the JIRA Server API reference... https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/server/#api/2/issue .. Be sure to note the difference between POST and PUT when performing different actions.