# Json value print TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have below dictionary in python

```
 >>> dict = {"name":"myname", "class": "10", "score %": "60"}
```

I have converted from dictionary to json format like below

```
>>> json_format = json.dumps(dict)
>>> print json_format
{"score %": "60", "name": "myname", "class": "10"}
```

I am trying to get value of key from json_format variable:

```
  >>> print json_format["name"]
```

I am getting below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Please help me where i am doing mistake.

Comment: `json.dumps(dict)` creates a string. It is no longer accessible as a python dictionary object. You're actually creating `'{"name": "myname", "class": "10", "score %": "60"}'`

Comment: May be you should check [What is the difference between json.dumps and json.load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911336/what-is-the-difference-between-json-dumps-and-json-load)

Comment: Again required to convert back to dict and print ?

Comment: `json.loads(json_format)`

Answer (score 1):

`json.dumps()` returns the string representation so you can't access it like a json datatype.

You need to do something like this:

```
import json
dict = {"name":"myname", "class": "10", "score %": "60"}
json_format = json.dumps(dict)
```

If you check the json_format `type()`:

```
print(type(json_format))
```

Output:

```
<class 'str'>
```

So you need to do this:

```
json_format = json.loads(json_format)
print(json_format["name"])
```